# Automated REST/Jetty Server startup in CMake buildsystem

Tags: c, maven, jenkins, cmake, jetty

I have multiple C Unit Test programs that connects to a REST Server and sends/receives some data. I usually open a new terminal and start the server by typing `mvn jetty:run` and in a different terminal I do perform the Unit Tests by entering `make test`. The problems is that the Code is tested by a Jenkins server and the Unit Tests fail because they can't connect to a REST Server. I tried opening the REST Server with a CMake `execute_process(COMMAND mvn jetty:run)`, but then the Unit Tests never ends because the server is waiting for input. I also tried opening the server with `mvn jetty:start`, but the Server doesn't seem to remain active after the command finishes. It just tells "Jetty Server started", but I can't see any running REST Server nor make a connection with it and `mvn jetty:stop` says there is no active server running. I also tried opening the server in parallel using the &, but Maven blocks it. The attempt to open the Jetty Server in parallel using a ShellScript that I would execute using the `&` didn't work either. Also the problem is that when I execute the Server in parallel I don't know when the server has started up and is ready for the Unit Tests to begin.

The best solution would be if I could open the server, perform the Unit Tests and close the server afterwards fully automated with CMake.

Comment: Simply create new CMake target (say, `test1`) which executes preparing, testing, and finalizing steps in order: `COMMAND mvn jetty:run COMMAND make test COMMAND mvn jetty:stop`.

Comment: As I already said when executing jetty:run the server starts and waits for input/connection and essentially blocks the terminal for any further input, the execution stops there and won't continues till the server eventually decides it has waited long enough and will shutdown itself.